# Check existing RSA Key Container

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I have created an RSA Key Container by using the following code.The keys are created in the container and I can encrypt/decrypt in the container successfully.

```
public static void CreateKeyContainer()
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = null;

        try
        {
            var cryptoParameters = new CspParameters();
            cryptoParameters.KeyContainerName = "MyContainer";
            cryptoParameters.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
            rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cryptoParameters);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (rsa != null)
            {
                rsa.Clear();
                rsa.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Before the call of the CreateKeyContainer method, I would like to ensure whether the keys already exist or not in the specified container. I have changed the flag to CpsProviderFlags.UseExistingKey.

```
public static bool CheckIfKeysExist()
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = null;

        try
        {
            var cryptoParameters = new CspParameters();
            cryptoParameters.KeyContainerName = "MyContainer";
            cryptoParameters.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey;
            rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cryptoParameters);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (rsa != null)
            {
                rsa.Clear();
                rsa.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

However, by executing this method, it always throws a Cryptographic Exception that "Keyset does not exist", regardless of the existence of the key container.

How can I check if the key container already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating the Key in Machine Key Store set the Flags property as shown below:

```
cryptoParameters.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey | | CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
```

Comment: use one | for binary OR

Comment: The problem is that if it doesn't exist, an exception will be thrown. Is there any way to tell without throwing an exception? I mean I can catch the exception and return a boolean, but I really don't want to resort to that.